# How to Interpret p-value from multi-curve Kaplan-Meier Graph

Tags: survival, p-value, interpretation

I've generated a few KM graphs from TCGA data. I am unsure of what the p-value provided by the function and the graphed chart indicates. I just looked through the survival.pdf from cran but am still unsure.

I currently believe that the p-value indicates with a 0.95 confidence that there is statistically significant variance of survival probabilities over time between the curves.

Here is a representative graph:
[image: Kaplan meier graph with p value]

I think the relevant code snippets are:

```
survival_object <- Surv(time = cesc_survival_data$survival_time, event = cesc_survival_data$survival_status)
#Fit the survival data to a curve that is defined by the quartiles of zscore SLC2A2
quartiles_SLC2A2_expression_survival_curve <- survfit(survival_object ~ zscore_value_SLC2A2_quartile, data = cesc_survival_data)
#Generate a graph of survival object/expression quartile curve of zscore SLC2A2 median quartiles
ggsurvplot(quartiles_SLC2A2_expression_survival_curve, data = cesc_survival_data, 
           #conf.int = TRUE,
           pval = TRUE,
           fun = "pct",
           risk.table = TRUE,
           size = 1,
           linetype = "strata",
           #palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
           legend = "bottom",
           legend.title = "Expression Quartiles",
           legend.labs = c("Low Exp.", "Med. Low Exp.", "Med. High Exp.", "High Exp."),
           caption = "SLC2A2 Expression Quartile Survival Curve"
)
```

Do I have the correct interpretation of this p-value? Is there NEARLY a significant variance in the survival probabilities of these four groups? And if not, what is the p-value trying to tell me?

Comment: If your alpha level = 0.05, then your p gives you the probability for null hypothesis (the survival of the studied groups are equal). As your p = 0.052, you do not have sufficient evidence for alternative hypothesis. Also, there seems to be a risk for type II error - sample size may not be sufficient for detecting actual differences. This can be well seen if you add confidence intervals to this plot (they should be wide). Finally, CI-s would also allow to compare survival between different groups using eyeballing.

Comment: Thanks st4co4! Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Bligh on Biostars posted this answer to my question, mirrored there.

The default p-value that is calculated is the log-rank p-value. It is testing the null hypothesis that each of your strata (survival groups) has the same survival probability.

I show this in a previous answer, here: A: survfit(Surv()) P-value interpretation for 3 survival curves?
https://www.biostars.org/p/401657/#401759

In my other answer, I also show how you can use the coxph() function to generate p-values for each pairwise stratum / curve.

Looking at your data, it p-value is not statistically significant and your data-points are sparse after ~75 days.